# How can I change the code below to produce horizontal annotations in Stanford NLP?

Tags: command-line-interface, stanford-nlp, output-formatting

When I use the code `java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma -file 1.txt -outputFormat conll -output.columns lemma` to annotate this example sentence

> Stanford University is located in California. It is a great university, founded in 1891.

I get the result like this: [Annotations formatted vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzvxb.png) But I couldn't manage to output the annotations horizontally. For instance, I could not have the annotated lemmas or POS output this way in a txt file:

> Stanford University be locate in California. it be a great university, found in 1891.

I know this must be a very silly question, but it has been bugging me for a while. I know too little about scripting and there's no one around me that I could turn to. I will be very grateful for any generous help to help me modify the code to meet my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few alternate output formats which you could use.  From `StanfordCoreNLP.java`:

```
public enum OutputFormat { TEXT, TAGGED, XML, JSON, CONLL, CONLLU, INLINEXML, SERIALIZED, CUSTOM }
```

`SERIALIZED` is a protobuf format, probably not too helpful.  `CUSTOM` literally means you write custom code to handle the produced objects.  You already know you don't like `CONLL`, which probably rules out `CONLLU` as well.
Perhaps one of the others will be more to your liking.

Although I will also say that turning my laptop 90 degrees to the right made the output horizontal.

Comment: Many thanks for the insights (except for that turning laptop 90 degrees one). I will try the alternative formats.